# Establecer el tamaño de H1 en un div con HTML y Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

vengo trabajando en un div de bienvenida para mi pagina, el problema esque los `h1` se ven demasiados pequeños, mi duda seria agrandar hasta el `boton` a un tamaño comprensible

**este es la imagen que me genera con el codigo actual :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto mi codigo HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="portfolioModal-19" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel-12" aria-hidden="true">                                  
                                    <div class="modal-content text-white">
                                        <div class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            <div class="lr"><div class="rl"></div></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="container">
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" align="center">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h1  class="modal-title" >BIENVENIDOS</h1>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <h1 class="modal-title" > A </h1>
                                                        <br>                                                                
                                                        <h1 class="modal-title" ><span class="text-main">LCN PERÚ</span></h1>
                                                        <div class="divider divider-sm divider-icon divider-white">//</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" align="center">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-main" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa  fa-hand-o-up"></i> Entrar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con `css` apuntando a tu `h1` usando la clase `modal-title` `h1.modal-title{ font-size: XXpx}`

Comment: Pero eso descuadra a mis otros `H1`

Comment: Puedes hacer que al `h1` quieres apuntar asignarle un id y usarlo en vez de la clase o el tag de html

Comment: @Ivan, quitale <div class="container"> y su  </div> que esta  dentro de tu modal, luego podes usar los estilos que te indican.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la propiedad de `font-size` en un titulo especifico de esta forma:

```
<h1  class="modal-title" style="font-size: 100px" >BIENVENIDOS</h1>
```

Y así no alteras los demás `h1`

Comment: Gracias, espero que  votes un +1

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores Cuidado al agregar estilos inline. Pueden darte problemas en un futuro. Deberías de usar IDs o clases para agregar estilos y tener separados tus estilos del HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es hacer referencia únicamente a un `h1` y modificarle su tamaño puedes asignarle un ID (que hace referencia a un `h1` únicamente) y asignarle un tamaño mediante la propiedad `font-size`.

Ejemplo:

```css
#grande{
   font-size: 50px;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1> Este es el tamaño normal <h1>
<h1 id="grande">Este es un tamaño mas grande de lo normal</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres aumentar el tamaño de esos tres, podrías agregarles una clase y luego darle las propiedades que quieras, ejemplo:

```css
h1.titulo-grande {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1  class="modal-title titulo-grande" >BIENVENIDOS</h1>
  <br>
  <h1 class="modal-title titulo-grande" > A </h1>
  <br>                                                                 <h1 class="modal-title titulo-grande" ><span class="text-main">LCN PERÚ</span></h1>
  <div class="divider divider-sm divider-icon divider-white">//</div>
</div>
```